# Ruby on Rails: reference to ActiveRecord is a snapshot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, reference, snapshot

Say I have a class `User` that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, and it has a `:name` attribute. Then in the console I create a new user by:

```
> user1 = User.create(name: 'Bob')
=> #<User id: 1, name: 'Bob'>
```

Then I update the user's name to 'Bob'. Note I'm not doing `user1.update_attribute`.

```
> User.find_by(name: 'Bob').update_attribute(:name, 'Bill')
```

Now typing in:

```
> User.find_by(name: 'Bob')
=> nil
> User.find_by(name: 'Bill')
=> #<User id: 1, name: 'Bill'>
```

Which is what I expected. However, when I check my `user1` reference I get:

```
> user1
=> #<User id: 1, name: 'Bob'>
```

Somehow this still has the old user name. Is user1 not a reference to the ActiveRecord? Is it a snapshot of some sort?

Comment: `user1.reload` should fix the problem [`reload`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what it still has in the memory. `user1.reload` will do a new select and return refreshed record.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord fetches data from the database and converts it to objects. So yes, it's effectively a snapshot. There's just no good way to determine if any of its values changed in the meantime. While some database engines offer some sort of listen/notify, doing that for every single object is major (and useless most of the time) performance overhead.

There are alternative ORMs that adhere to "the same row is the same object" principle (such as [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/why.html), see *"Identity map"*), but under certain circumstances that's also unreliable: the object in the meantime may have been modified by a different process your ORM has no idea about.

So ActiveRecord offers *a compromise*: it caches the object, but leaves you with `reload` method, that refreshes the object with data from the database **in-place**, **returning itself**, so you can fetch it and act on it without extra assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Your `user1` is not updated automatically. You need to call `user1.reload` first.